# Populate ListBox with devices, showing their names, using C++/WinRT?

Tags: c++, uwp-xaml, c++-winrt

I have a DeviceSelector class, which displays a list of devices to select. I would like to do this programmatically, without the use of XAML files.
As I find it difficult to use the ListBox control properly from C++, I have the following questions:

- How do I use the `DisplayMemberPath` property correctly to display the `Name` property in the ListBox? A path to the property should be passed in, but this does not seem to work in my program for some reason.
- Is it possible to use the`ItemsSource` property to populate the ListBox using a Collection? It is not clear from the docs what to pass as a parameter and there are not that many non-XAML C++ examples.

Below I have my simplified DeviceSelector class and I have provided a simple application for troubleshooting purposes.

#### Edit 1:

The DisplayMemberPath not working like I expect it to, is not specific to C++/WinRT. I tried to implement it using XAML and code behind, using:

```
<ListBox x:Name="DeviceSelector" DisplayMemberPath="Name">
...
</ListBox>
```

After populating the ListBox with the devices, it doesn't show the names either.

---

#### DeviceSelector.h

```
#pragma once

#include <winrt\Windows.Foundation.h>
#include <winrt\Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.h>


struct DeviceSelector : winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::ListBox
{
    DeviceSelector();
    winrt::Windows::Foundation::IAsyncAction ShowAllAsync();
};
```

---

#### DeviceSelector.cpp

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "DeviceSelector.h"

#include <winrt\Windows.Devices.Enumeration.h>
#include <winrt\Windows.Foundation.h>
#include <winrt\Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.h>


using namespace winrt::Windows::Devices::Enumeration;
using namespace winrt::Windows::Foundation;
using namespace winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls;


DeviceSelector::DeviceSelector()
{
    //DOES NOT WORK:
    //DisplayMemberPath(L"Name");
}


IAsyncAction DeviceSelector::ShowAllAsync()
{
    DeviceInformationCollection devices = co_await DeviceInformation::FindAllAsync();

    //DOES NOT WORK:
    //ItemsSource(devices);

    //DOES WORK:
    //But does not display device names, without the right DisplayMemberPath.
    for (DeviceInformation device : devices)
    {
        Items().Append(device);
    }
}
```

---

#### Main.cpp

```
#include "pch.h"

#include <winrt\Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.h>
#include <winrt\Windows.UI.Xaml.h>

#include "DeviceSelector.h"


using namespace winrt;
using namespace winrt::Windows::ApplicationModel::Activation;
using namespace winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml;


struct App : ApplicationT<App>
{
    DeviceSelector selector;

    void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs const &)
    {
        //Create window with a DeviceSelector instance.
        Window window = Window::Current();
        window.Content(selector);
        window.Activate();

        //Populate selector with devices.
        selector.ShowAllAsync();
    }

    static void Initialize(ApplicationInitializationCallbackParams const &)
    {
        make<App>();
    }

    static void Start()
    {
        Application::Start(App::Initialize);
    }
};

int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE, HINSTANCE, PWSTR, int)
{
    App::Start();
}
```

---

#### pch.h

```
#pragma once

#pragma comment(lib, "windowsapp")

#include <winrt\Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.h>
#include <winrt\Windows.Devices.Enumeration.h>
#include <winrt\Windows.Foundation.h>
#include <winrt\Windows.Media.Devices.h>
#include <winrt\Windows.UI.Xaml.h>
#include <winrt\Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.h>
```

Comment: `//DOES WORK but does not display useful information, without the right DisplayMemberPath.` which property are you trying to display?

Comment: The 'Name' property, as stated in the first question. I'll edit the comment to make it  more clear.

Comment: Does `DeviceInformation` have a `Name` property? If so, have your tried doing: `Items().Append(device.Name);`?

Comment: Yes, you'll have to use `PropertyValue::CreateString()` to make that work. Even then you are only enumerating strings of names, not the actual devices. So if you then select the name, you can only get that string returned, not the device itself. Then there is no way I know of to get the actual device back from just that name, you'll need an ID for that to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hooking up Bindings the way you describe requires either:

1. Xaml Compiler support (which is coming soon, but still in preview)

or

2. You need to point at an object implementing [`ICustomPropertyProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.ICustomPropertyProvider) and `ICustomProperty` (and `INotifyPropertyChanged` if you want your `ListBox` items to update when the data value changes).

This is because `DataMemberPath` relies on runtime reflection (it's querying, at runtime, for a property with a given name - more details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-in-depth)). A plain old WinRT class doesn't provide that functionality, so you'd have to wrap it in something that can.

If you decided to go the ICustomPropertyProvider route, here's a hacked together sample implementation that hooks up just the `Name` property. This was just a quick proof of concept; there are far better and more extensible ways of doing this:

```
#include <winrt/Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.Devices.Enumeration.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.Foundation.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.UI.Xaml.Interop.h>

using namespace winrt;

using namespace Windows::ApplicationModel::Activation;
using namespace Windows::Devices::Enumeration;
using namespace Windows::Foundation;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Data;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Interop;

struct DeviceInfoCustomProperty : implements<DeviceInfoCustomProperty, ICustomProperty>
{
    DeviceInfoCustomProperty(bool canRead, bool canWrite, hstring name, TypeName type)
        : m_CanRead(canRead)
        , m_CanWrite(canWrite)
        , m_Name(std::move(name))
        , m_Type(std::move(type))
    {
    }

    bool CanRead() const noexcept
    {
        return m_CanRead;
    }

    bool CanWrite() const noexcept
    {
        return m_CanWrite;
    }

    hstring Name() const noexcept
    {
        return m_Name;
    }

    TypeName Type() const noexcept
    {
        return m_Type;
    }

    IInspectable GetIndexedValue(const IInspectable&, const IInspectable&) const noexcept { return nullptr; }
    IInspectable GetValue(const IInspectable& target) const;
    void SetIndexedValue(const IInspectable&, const IInspectable&, const IInspectable&) const noexcept {}
    void SetValue(const IInspectable&, const IInspectable&) const noexcept {}

    IInspectable m_Object;
    bool m_CanRead;
    bool m_CanWrite;
    hstring m_Name;
    TypeName m_Type;
};

struct DeviceInfoWrapper : implements<DeviceInfoWrapper, ICustomPropertyProvider>
{
    explicit DeviceInfoWrapper(DeviceInformation info)
        : m_info(std::move(info))
    {
    }

    TypeName Type() const noexcept
    {
        return xaml_typename<DeviceInformation>();
    }

    ICustomProperty GetCustomProperty(const hstring& name)
    {
        if (name == L"Name")
        {
            return make<DeviceInfoCustomProperty>(true, false, name, xaml_typename<hstring>());
        }
        return nullptr;
    }

    ICustomProperty GetIndexedProperty(const hstring&, const TypeName&)
    {
        return nullptr;
    }

    hstring GetStringRepresentation()
    {
        return L"DeviceWrapper";
    }

    DeviceInformation m_info;
};

IInspectable DeviceInfoCustomProperty::GetValue(const IInspectable& target) const
{
    // Temporary workaround if preview SDK <= 17095
    auto wrapper = from_abi<DeviceInfoWrapper>(target.as<ICustomPropertyProvider>());
    // else
    auto wrapper = target.as<DeviceInfoWrapper>();

    if (m_Name == L"Name")
    {
        return box_value(wrapper->m_info.Name());
    }
    return nullptr;
}

struct DeviceSelector : winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::ListBoxT<DeviceSelector>
{
    DeviceSelector()
    {
        DisplayMemberPath(L"Name");
        SelectionChanged([](const IInspectable&, const SelectionChangedEventArgs& args)
        {
            for (const auto& item : args.AddedItems())
            {
                // DEBUG - verifying that this is, in fact, the object
                auto wrapper = item.as<DeviceInfoWrapper>();
                wrapper->m_info.Name().c_str();
            }
        });
    }

    fire_and_forget ShowAllAsync()
    {
        DeviceInformationCollection devices = co_await DeviceInformation::FindAllAsync();
        for (const auto& device : devices)
        {
            Items().Append(make<DeviceInfoWrapper>(device));
        }
    }
};

struct App : ApplicationT<App>
{
    DeviceSelector selector;

    void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs const &)
    {

        Window window = Window::Current();
        window.Content(selector.try_as<UIElement>());
        window.Activate();

        selector.ShowAllAsync();
    }
};

int __stdcall wWinMain(HINSTANCE, HINSTANCE, PWSTR, int)
{
    Application::Start([](auto &&) { make<App>(); });
}
```

Comment: I don't have the latest SDK yet, which provides box_value and xaml_typename. I suppose equivalent code for `box_value()`, would be `PropertyValue::CreateString()` in this case, to get an `IInspectable` from the `Name` member. However I can't find equivalent code for xaml_typename. There is no C++/WinRT source online for the latest SDK to see how it is definede, so no way for me to investigate. Could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Could I construct a `TypeName` instance with `(TypeName).Name = typeid(DeviceInformation).name;` and `(TypeName).Kind = TypeKind::Metadata;` or something?

Comment: typeid isn't going to work for what XAML's TypeName wants. You'll really want to get the SDK and rely on the official implementation, because the rules are... odd. For starters, winrt::name_of<T>() **usually** works, but the 5 WF structs don't have their namespaces stripped off. The primitive types (int, string, guid, etc) all use TypeKind::Primitive, and everything else gets TypeKind::Metadata. That might unblock you for now, until you can get the official implementation. Be warned, trying to implement this yourself will void your warranty. :)

Comment: I get `error C2787: 'DeviceInfoWrapper': no GUID has been associated with this object` when running this code. Any way to get `DeviceInfoWrapper` from `const IInspectable &`?

Comment: Oops. I didn't realize that code depends on a new feature that just missed the 17095 preview - the ability to QI directly to an implements<T>-derived class. This feature will be present in the next preview SDK.


I've edited my answer to provide some workaround helper code in the meantime.

Comment: I knew about the Interop Helper functions, but was never sure how to use them. This is a great example, thanks!